# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException , arrays with numbers

Tags: java, arrays

i wrote a code but I can't find the error which is shown in the output. The program has in input some numbers that i put in an array.

It has three methods:

1. invert the array;
2. find the max and min;
3. average of the numbers inserted.

Here's my code:

```
package sequenza;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class SequenzaClass {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] numeri;
    int dim;
    int max;
    int min;
    int media;
    int somma;
    int DIMENSIONE_MAX;

    public SequenzaClass(int dim, int max, int min, int media, int somma, int DIMENSIONE) {
        this.dim = dim;
        this.max = max;
        this.min = min;
        this.media = media;
        this.somma = somma;
        this.DIMENSIONE_MAX = 10;
    }

    SequenzaClass() {
        numeri = new int[DIMENSIONE_MAX];
        int dim = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int media = 0;
        int somma = 0;
        int DIMENSIONE_MAX = 10;
    }

    public Scanner getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(Scanner input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

     public void Inserisci(int dim) {
        System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to insert? ");
        dim = input.nextInt();
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            System.out.print("Number for position [" + i + "]:");
            numeri[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
     }

    public int getDim() {
        return dim;
    }

    public void setDim(int dim) {
        this.dim = dim;
    }

    public int[] getNumeri() {
        return numeri;
    }

    public void setNumeri(int[] numeri) {
        this.numeri = numeri;
    }


    public int getMax() {
        int max = numeri[0];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            if (numeri[i] > max) {
                max = numeri[i];
            }
        }
        return max;
    }

    public void setMax(int max) {
        this.max = max;
    }

    public int getMin() {
        int min = numeri[0];
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            if (numeri[i] < min) {
                min = numeri[i];
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    public void setMin(int min) {
        this.min = min;
    }

    public int getSomma() {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            somma = somma + numeri[i];
        }
        return somma;
    }

    public void setSomma(int somma) {
        this.somma = somma;
    }

    public int getMedia() {
        media = getSomma() / dim;
        return media;
    }

    public void setMedia(int media) {
        this.media = media;
    }

    public int getDIMENSIONE_MAX() {
        return DIMENSIONE_MAX;
    }

    public void setDIMENSIONE_MAX(int DIMENSIONE_MAX) {
        this.DIMENSIONE_MAX = DIMENSIONE_MAX;
    }



    public void Contrario(int dim) {

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < (dim / 2); i++) {
            int k = numeri[dim - i - 1];
            numeri[dim - i - 1] = k;
        }
        System.out.println("The inverted vector is: " +numeri[i]);

    }

}
```

```
package sequenza;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int DIMENSIONE_MAX = 10;
        int[] numeri = new int[DIMENSIONE_MAX];
        int dim = 0;
        int max = 0;
        int min = 0;
        int media = 0;
        int somma = 0;
        int scelta = 1;

        SequenzaClass sequenza1 = new SequenzaClass();

        sequenza1.Inserisci(dim);

        while (scelta != 0) {
            System.out.println("1) Invert numbers");
            System.out.println("2) Max and min");
            System.out.println("3) Avarage");
            scelta = input.nextInt();

            switch (scelta) {
                case 1:
                    sequenza1.Contrario(dim);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println(sequenza1.getMax());
                    System.out.println(sequenza1.getMin());
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println(sequenza1.getMedia());
                    break;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your full stacktrace so we can see what line of code threw the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a check on **ALL METHODS THAT ACCESS** `numeri` to make sure the index is less than `DIMENSIONE_MAX` or `numeri.length` if you plan on setting the size of the array at runtime.

```
 public void Inserisci(int dim) {
    System.out.print("How many numbers do you want to insert? ");
    dim = input.nextInt();
    if (dim > DIMENSIONE_MAX || dim < 0) {
       // handle this. it can't happen
    } else {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < dim; i++) {
            System.out.print("Number for position [" + i + "]:");
            numeri[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
    }
 }
```

Also note that this is a very bad idea

```
public void setDIMENSIONE_MAX(int DIMENSIONE_MAX) {
    this.DIMENSIONE_MAX = DIMENSIONE_MAX;
}
```

This will have no effect on the size of your array but will cause the check I previously posted above to fail. The size of your array is fixed when it is created. So if this method is called after the array is created bad things can happen if you are using it as an indicator of the size of the array. If you are using `DIMENSIONE_MAX` as an indicator of array size it should most likely be declared `final` as a class member not in the function if you are using it define the size of an array.

```
private static final int DIMENSIONE_MAX = 10;
```

**EDIT**
Actually I just looked at your code again and noticed you are defining this value in 3 different locations. That needs fixed as it is also bad practice.

This declaration is doing absolutely nothing:

```
SequenzaClass() {
    numeri = new int[DIMENSIONE_MAX];
    int dim = 0;
    int max = 0;
    int min = 0;
    int media = 0;
    int somma = 0;
    int DIMENSIONE_MAX = 10;
}
```

did you mean:

```
SequenzaClass() {
    numeri = new int[DIMENSIONE_MAX];
    this.dim = 0;
    this.max = 0;
    this.min = 0;
    this.media = 0;
    this.somma = 0;
    this.DIMENSIONE_MAX = 10;
}
```

Please also note that if the default constructor above is called `DIMENSIONE_MAX` has not been set until after the array is created. So you are essentially creating an array of size 0 then setting a **LOCAL** `DIMENSIONE_MAX` to 10 which does nothing for the class member `DIMENSIONE_MAX`.